# Dump a user's mailbox to a file (e.g., .mbox) from server for archival

Tags: terminal, mail.app, email, server.app

My company has a policy that when an employee leaves, we need to dump their e-mail account and write it to a DVD to archive it.

How do you dump a particular user's e-mail into a .mbox or other archivable file format from the server (without access to the client-side of the user's e-mail account)?

I didn't see any options in the Server.app GUI, so is there a Terminal command I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this via Terminal on the server.

```
cd /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mail
sudo ls -l users | grep <username>
```

(where  is the username you're looking for)

This returns the user's ID (e.g., 006638A6-9664-4CB4-8814-525A253B6E33)

```
sudo cp -a <id>/ ~/Desktop/<username>
```

This will copy the user's mail directory to a directory on the desktop. I then dumped that directory onto an external hard drive used for archiving former employees' mailboxes.

Thankfully we'll be switching away from macOS Server (which will be removing the Mail service in an upcoming update) to Exchange, so I won't have to deal with this anymore!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not exactly what you want as it is not work being done directly on the files stored on the server, but I have always just changed the user's password, then used Mail.app to connect to the IMAP account, and used Mail.app to export the data. If you want to take it off the server, move the mailboxes or content into folders "On My Mac" and export from there.

For huge amounts of email, this is slow and not very disk-space efficient. For more modest amounts of mail, it is fairly straightforward.